# host a java project (war) on IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, jetty

I created a new site `sample` on IIS.
I put in :

- C:\tools\jetty\webapps : the war `sample.war`
- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sample the file `web.config`

--> as result : navigate with **http://localhost:1122/sample**, I got the desired content.

My problem is to add a `Host name` to the site `sample` in IIS to be able to create a certificate.

Could you please help me solving that issue ?.
Big thanks.